# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). sklearn python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

i have problem with sklearn Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20,random_state=109)
```

but when I check :

```
print(np.where(X_train.values >= np.finfo(np.float64).max))
print(np.any(np.isnan(X_train)))
print(np.where(X_test.values >= np.finfo(np.float64).max))
print(np.any(np.isnan(X_test)))
```

the result like this:

```
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
False
(array([], dtype=int64), array([], dtype=int64))
False
```

what must i do.. please help me

Comment: Could you check your `y` labels too to see if there are some invalid values?

Comment: Done and the result is False

Comment: Have you ever tried `numpy.isinf`?

Comment: yeah, I tried it and the results was TRUE

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. Maybe you can set `np.isinf(X)` to a big number to see if you still have the same problem.